# Problem using vector of pointers (with code) C++ (and doubts regarding the convenience of its use)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, operators

First of all, as you will see, I am a noobie with C++. I am sure you can teach me some things.

I am having a problem with a small example code I am using for getting used to pointers and vectors of pointers, and I have a doubt regarding the convenience of using a vector of pointers for my case.

1.) **Convenience of its use**: I am writing a small C++ software. Within this software the user can create through a GUI certain objects (called modules), with an undefined amount of different parameters inside (they could be a lot). For the shake of performance/saving memory, I thought it would be good for its management having a vector of pointers to them, instead of allocating the objects themselves in a vector. The user would also be capable of deleting these objects(modules). ***Is it sensible to use a vector of pointers in this context?*** 
I also thought of using references to them, but I saw I should rather use a reference wrapper.

2.) **Particular example**: In the next paragraphs find an example of a simple code I am using for practicing with the use of pointers and vector of pointers.

file NumberClass.h

```
#ifndef NUNMBERCLASS_H
#define NUNMBERCLASS_H

class Number{
    private:
        int n;

    public:
        Number();
        Number(int n);
        int square();
        int getNumber();
};

#endif
```

file NumberClass.cpp

```
#include "NumberClass.h"

Number::Number(){n=0;}
Number::Number(int m){n=m;}
int Number::square(){return (n*n);}
int Number::getNumber(){return n;}
```

file NumbersContainerClass.h

```
#ifndef NUMBERSCONTAINERCLASS_H
#define NUMBERSCONTAINERCLASS_H
#include <vector>
#include "NumberClass.h"

class NumbersContainer{
    private:
        std::vector<Number*> numCont;
    public:
        void numberPush_back(Number n);
        Number* getNumberByPosition(int j);
        int sizeMethod();
        int capacityMethod();
};

#endif
```

file NumbersContainerClass.cpp

```
#include "NumbersContainerClass.h"

void NumbersContainer::numberPush_back(Number n){numCont.push_back(&n);}
Number* NumbersContainer::getNumberByPosition(int j){
    return numCont[j];
    }
int NumbersContainer::sizeMethod(){return numCont.size();}
int NumbersContainer::capacityMethod(){return numCont.capacity();}
```

file main.cpp

```
#include "NumbersContainerClass.h"
#include "NumberClass.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    Number n1;
    Number n2(2);
    Number n3(3);
    Number n4(4);
    Number n5(5);

std::cout << n1.getNumber() << std::endl;
std::cout << "n1 Address: " << &n1 << std::endl;

std::cout << n2.getNumber() << std::endl;
std::cout << "n2 Address: " << &n2 << std::endl;

std::cout << n3.getNumber() << std::endl;
std::cout << "n3 Address: " << &n3 << std::endl;

std::cout << n4.getNumber() << std::endl;
std::cout << "n4 Address: " << &n4 << std::endl;

std::cout << n5.getNumber() << std::endl;
std::cout << "n5 Address: " << &n5 << std::endl;


    NumbersContainer container;

    std::cout << "n1 Address: " << &n1 << std::endl;
    container.numberPush_back(n1);
    int k=0; //Here I just wanted to check if something changed by pasing the parameter like this.
    std::cout << (*(container.getNumberByPosition(k))).getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(k)->getNumber() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "n2 Address: " << &n2 << std::endl;
    container.numberPush_back(n2);
    std::cout << (*(container.getNumberByPosition(1))).getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(1)->getNumber() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "n3 Address: " << &n3 << std::endl;
    container.numberPush_back(n3);
    std::cout << (*(container.getNumberByPosition(2))).getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(2)->getNumber() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "n4 Address: " << &n4 << std::endl;
    container.numberPush_back(n4);
    std::cout << (*(container.getNumberByPosition(3))).getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(3)->getNumber() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "n5 Address: " << &n5 << std::endl;
    container.numberPush_back(n5);
    std::cout << (*(container.getNumberByPosition(4))).getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(4)->getNumber() << std::endl;

std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(4) << std::endl;
std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(3) << std::endl;
std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(2) << std::endl;
std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(1) << std::endl;
std::cout << container.getNumberByPosition(0) << std::endl;

std::cout << container.sizeMethod() << std::endl;
std::cout << container.capacityMethod() << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

and the output to this is:

```
0
n1 Address: 0x7ffd73484028
2
n2 Address: 0x7ffd7348402c
3
n3 Address: 0x7ffd73484030
4
n4 Address: 0x7ffd73484034
5
n5 Address: 0x7ffd73484038
n1 Address: 0x7ffd73484028
32765
32765
n2 Address: 0x7ffd7348402c
32765
32765
n3 Address: 0x7ffd73484030
32765
32765
n4 Address: 0x7ffd73484034
32765
32765
n5 Address: 0x7ffd73484038
32765
32765
0x7ffd73483ff4
0x7ffd73483ff4
0x7ffd73483ff4
0x7ffd73483ff4
0x7ffd73483ff4
5
8
```

The code works fine when I return directly a Number type object, so "Number NumbersContainer::getNumberByPosition(int k)". 
Nevertheless, when I try to return a pointer to a Number (Number* NumbersContainer::getNumberByPosition(int k)", although apparently I get a reference to the desired Number type object (since I can use the operator -> or dereferenciate the output pointer and use the function defined for Number "int Number::getNumber()"), the result I get is nonsense to me. **What am I missing or I did not understand?** I have played around for a long while with the code, but I always end up at this point, so I assume I did not understand something.

Thank you in advance! Any correction/remark/observartions next to the exact questions are more than welcome.

Comment: you might be better off storing the `Numbers` by value and returning them by value.

Comment: The issue with your code doing things this way is that everywhere you are storing the address local variables, or as the answer I posted states, you're storing the address of a temporary.  Usually when dealing with pointers, somewhere dynamic allocation is used to create the objects (either with `new`, or better yet use a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr`), which your code fails to do anywhere.  Storing address of locals or temporaries is, for the former, error-prone and restrictive (the object has to be in scope), and for the latter, usually just a plain bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a vector `v` of `Number`s and you need to add another one, you give `v.push_back` a `Number` and it places a copy of that `Number` at the end of the vector. If it had been a vector of `double`, no difference, `push_back` expects a `double`.

So if it's a vector of `Number*`, you'd expect `push_back` to take a `Number*`, not a `Number`, and to push a copy of the pointer, which is not at all the same thing as a pointer to a copy of the pointed-at object.

But you've written your `numberPush_back` member function to take a `Number n`, not a `Number* p`. And it needs to add a pointer to a `Number` to the container. Where can it get such a pointer? It can't use `&n`, because `n` is a local automatic variable containing a *copy* of the argument, and that variable's lifetime will end immediately, when `numberPush_back` returns. (That's what you do, but it doesn't work because it adds a dangling pointer to the container.)

You could make a new dynamically-allocated `Number` copied from `n`, and add a pointer to that new object. But then you'll need some mechanism to explicitly delete the dynamically-allocated copy.

So that leaves you with either accepting the argument by reference (`Number& n`) or insisting that the caller give you a pointer. In both cases, you need the caller to know that they are responsible for ensuring that the `Number` whose pointer ends up in the container lives at least as long as the container.

Anyway, the whole point was to avoid making copies, no?

That's not to say that containers of pointers are useless. They can be useful, but they always require extra thought about memory management. If you just want to avoid copying, you're better off using the `emplace_back` idiom, which takes as arguments the values used to *construct* the object, and constructs it in-place in the container.

Comment: I was reviewing your answer and there is something I don't find clear. You are focusing on the push_back function, but I think this is not the problem.
I have another version of the code with only one difference: the function ```Number NumbersContainer::getNumberByPosition(int j){
 Number* ptr = numCont[j];
 return *ptr;
 }
```
returns the object Number instead of a pointer to the object. This code works as expected. The push_back function is exactly the same. So I think it cannot be the source of the error. Am I right? The error it has to be somewhere else.

Comment: If that code seems to work, your tests are not adequate. Your container is full of the same dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious error:

You are storing the address of a temporary `Number` in this line:

`void NumbersContainer::numberPush_back(Number n){numCont.push_back(&n);}`

Thus after that function returns, the address-of `n` is no longer valid, since the lifetime of the temporary `n` has ended.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I take the other explanation as answer since it is more developed.

Comment: As I told to another colleague, I was reviewing your answer and there is something I don't find clear. 
You are also focusing on the push_back function, but I think this is not the problem. I have another version of the code with only one difference: the function Number NumbersContainer::getNumberByPosition(int j){ Number* ptr = numCont[j]; return *ptr; } returns the object Number instead of a pointer to the object. This code works as expected. The push_back function is exactly the same. So I think it cannot be the source of the error. Am I right? The error it has to be somewhere else.

Comment: C++ does not work this way.  You are storing the address of a temporary, which is *undefined behavior*, thus it is wrong.  Undefined behavior means that anything can happen.  That anything could be "working" for years, it could crash tomorrow, it may crash right away when run on another system.

Comment: Okei, I get it then! I thought the error could be something else since the other version worked apparently fine, but now is crystal clear. Thanks!